# TableLayout with images and text

Tags: android, tablelayout

I would like to show an image in the left cell and text in the right cell of a tablerow.

My problem is that the text-view is floating outside the visible screen, so I can't see the whole text. The text should break at the visible right end of screen. I've tried to set a `maxWidth` with a pixel value but that doesn't work.

Can anyone offer a solution to my problem. Maybe there is a better layout option?

my layout-definition:

```
<TableRow>
    <ImageView   
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:tint="#55ff0000"
      android:src="@drawable/bla"/> 
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/aboutblaImageText" 
        android:textSize="6pt" 
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:maxWidth="100px"    
        />        
</TableRow>
```

Comment: ok, the solution seems to be to use a nested linearlayout instead (outer linearlayout vertical, inner linearlayout horizontal). read about bad performance but it works

Comment: thats the best solution, nest into a linearlayout.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant by nested linear layouts? Are you wrapping each element in the tablerow in its own layout?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the stretchColumns and shrinkColumns properties of the Table. It worked for me.

```
<TableLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:stretchColumns="0"
  android:shrinkColumns="1">
```

I took the idea from the Jonathan Roth answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329175/android-table-layout-formatting-problems) post.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:shrinkColumns="1"` property to your `TableLayout`.