# Android table layout formatting problems

Tags: android, tablelayout

I can not get my TableLayout to fit inside the screen `when the text cell is large`, despite the text wraps `inside the cell`.

This is my TableLayout. A simple two-rows, two-columns table. Left column cells are `multiline`. If the text of one of these cell is large enought to break in two lines, the column is stretched to fill the entire screen and the right columns is pushed out of the screen.

Why? How can I force the full table to stay inside the screen?
Any hint is welcomed.

My TableLayout is the following:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Account 4 with a very large name to see if it breaks  on two or more lines"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:text="$400.00"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Account 5"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:text="$400.00"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

The code to display the layout is basic:

```
public class AccountBrowserTest 
    extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.accountbrowser_test);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Add android:`stretchColumns` and  `android:shrinkColumns` to the `TableLayout` element:

```
<TableLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:stretchColumns="1"
  android:shrinkColumns="1">
```

The `1` values are the columns you want the changes to occur. You can specify more that one value like this:

```
android:stretchColumns="0,1"
```

or if you want the changes to happen to all you columns like this:

```
android:stretchColumns="*"
```

Please look here for detailed information: http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/02/table-layout.html

Answer (score 8):

i had the same problem with my app and found the following solution:

```
<TableLayout 
   android:shrinkColumns="0"
   android:stretchColumns="1" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TableLayout>
```

This works fine with 2 Columns.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding

```
android:stretchColumns="0"
```

to the TableLayout element and setting

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

on the TextView that was too long.

Comment: and what exactly this means ? how did you figure out that this is the solution?

Answer (score 5):

inside table layout use shrinkColumns property for columns you want them to be allowed to shrink for fitting

easiest way is:

```
<TableLayout
android:shrinkColumns="*"/>
```

to shrink all columns or you can write  instead of " *" ,the column indices you want to shrink , which in your case will be

```
<TableLayout
android:shrinkColumns="0,1"/>
```

note that column indices  start from zero , so the latest code allows first (index=0) and second (index =1) columns to shrink.

Answer (score 1):

There is temporary fix, do:

```
   android:stretchColumns = " (number of actual col) - 1 "
```

No solution here worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the `wrap_content` for the width of your multiline cells.

You could try a few ways of giving it a more explicit width... i.e., setting the `width to 0`, and giving all of the cells a `layout_gravity = 1`.  That should cause each of the columns to take up an equal amount of width (or you can adjust if you want one to have more weight than the other).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not really good with layouts, so I only played around a bit with some values, and this seemed to work (I cannot give you a good explanation of why though):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Account 4 with a very large name to see if it breaks  on two or more lines"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <TextView
            android:text="$400.00"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.001"
        />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Account 5"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <TextView
            android:text="$400.00"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.001"
        />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Also note that I haven't tried this layout in an Activity, I only looked at it in the layout-view of the xml editor, but it looked fine there at least.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try manipulating stretchColumns and/or shrinkColumns in the TableLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you..
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Account 4 with a very large \n name to see if it breaks \n on two or more lines" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="$400.00" >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a combination of layout weights handled nicely. Check the example below. All the views in the row should get the same width using layout_weight=1 and layout_width=0dp.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*">
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/basicKeypadRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="T">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="R">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Y">
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/basicKeypadRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="R">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="O">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="W">
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>
```