# Fit button width in GridLayout column Android

Tags: android, android-gridlayout, column-width

I tried to create a GUI - GridLayout 2 rows & 2 cols (you can see in the image). I want the button width is fit the column (2) width. But the result is overflow.

[image]

Do you have ever get this kind of issue?

Here are my code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner_opacity_background"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="6">
    <!--Pick up-->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ci_pick_up" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/text_view_description"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="@string/pick_up" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectPickUp"
        style="@style/button_location"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/select_pick_up" />
    <!--Separator-->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:background="@color/primary" />
    <!--Drop off-->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ci_drop_off" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/text_view_description"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:text="@string/drop_off" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectDropOff"
        style="@style/button_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/select_pick_up" />
    <!--ConfirmedBookings-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShowConfirmedBookingsDialog"
        style="@style/button_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:text="@string/confirmed_booking" />
</GridLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShowBookDialog"
    style="@style/button_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:text="@string/book" />
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a piece of code? Can you sret you width to fill parent for that button instead of `android:layout_columnWeight="1"`

I would work with weights. With that you can specify your width in the parent that you have set match parent.

Reference: [Android Weights](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Also check: [Shrink and Stretch columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329175/android-table-layout-formatting-problems)

Comment: I edited my answer. You should use <row> </row> tags. Also refactor your code. It looks kinda messy.

Comment: Also depending on what API level tyou test: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016343/gridlayout-not-gridview-how-to-stretch-all-children-evenly

Comment: Did you try to change columnWeight to width and set it to fill parent ?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's still overflow :(

Comment: And set your gridlayout to fill-parent instead of match parent? Does that work?